# App crashing on calling function to read data from Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am a begginer in kotlin android.I am learning firestore. But on calling the function which i have created to recieve data my app crashes. (Adding to database function worked fine )

Here my function to recieve data

```
var isdbchanged:Boolean?=true
fun getdbchanged()
{
    val db=Firebase.firestore
    val ref=db.collection("Onlineusers").document("dbcondition")
    val change: status? =ref.get().result!!.toObject<status>()
    isdbchanged=change?.isdbchanged
}
```

basically it is to indicate whether database is changed or not(because i am not using realtime feature yet).

here is the data class

```
data class status(var isdbchanged:Boolean=true)
```

i declared these functions in seperate kotlin file in android studio and whenever i am calling this function from mainactivity my app crashes.

here's the function to add data which is working well.

```
fun initialdbwrite()
{
    val db=Firebase.firestore

    try {
        val ref = db.collection("Onlineusers")
        ref.document("Advanceurl").set(forurl("advancecppurl", urlsAdvancecpp))
        ref.document("Basicsurl").set(forurl("basicsurls", urlsbasics))
        ref.document("Oopsurl").set(forurl("oopsurls", urlsoops))
        ref.document("AboutActivity").set(aboutsection(aboutme))
        ref.document("dbcondition").set(status(false))
    }
    catch (e:Exception)
    {
        isdbchanged=true
    }

}
```

data classes

```
data class forurl(val acname:String,var theurls:MutableList<String>)

data class status(var isdbchanged:Boolean=true)

data class aboutsection(var aboutme:String=" ")
```

edit 1-
i added the success and failure listeners and write that code in main acticity instead of calling function . This time my app is not crashing but also it is not retrieving data.

```
val db=Firebase.firestore
        val ref=db.collection("Onlineusers").document("dbcondition")
        ref.get().addOnSuccessListener {
            val change:status?=it.toObject<status>()
            isdbchanged=change?.isdbchanged
        }
            .addOnFailureListener {
               Toast.makeText(this,it.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

also not showing any toast on failure listener, seems like this code is not doing anything on success and failure.

Comment: please share crash log

Comment: how to see crash log?

Comment: look at the bottom of android studio there is a button called "logcat" when you click it, you will see the crash log, if you don't set the filter to error, and then you will definitely see something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` does not return immediately with results.  You have to add a listener to the Task it returns to get the results asynchronously.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) for details.

This means you won't be able to write a function that returns the results of the query.  If you want a function that returns the results, you would have to make it a `suspend fun` and call it within a coroutine context.

Comment: i have'nt learned courutines yet. I saw the docs and added listeners. This time app is not crashing but also it is not retrieving data did'nt call any function this time , i write that code in main activity but it is not working  code- 'val db=Firebase.firestore
        val ref=db.collection("Onlineusers").document("dbcondition")
        ref.get().addOnSuccessListener {
            val change:status?=it.toObject<status>()
            isdbchanged=change?.isdbchanged
        }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                println("task failed"+it.message)
           ' }'